# How to get the "front" uiimageview from uiscrollviews?

Tags: iphone, uiscrollview, uiimage, zooming, subview

I have seen this question asked in other places...but no valid answers...

I have a UIScrollView that scrolls horizontally.  I have 3 photos in them...ie: subviews of the UIScrollView hold UIImageViews as below: (in this case, all the subviews of the UIScrollView are showing `path_to_file.png`... for ease of asking this question)

```
NSString *filepath = @"path_to_file.png";
UIScrollView *scroll = [[UIScrollView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0,self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height)];
scroll.delegate = self;
scroll.pagingEnabled = YES;
NSInteger numberOfViews = 3;
int maxImageWidth = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < numberOfViews; i++)  
{
    CGFloat yOrigin = i * self.view.frame.size.width;
    UIImage *imgWord = [[UIImage alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:filePath];
    UIImageView *imgWordView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:imgWord];
    [imgWord release];
    imgWordView.center = CGPointMake ((cell.contentView.frame.size.width/2) + yOrigin,imgWord.size.height/2);
    if (cell.contentView.frame.size.width > maxImageWidth)  {
    maxImageWidth = cell.contentView.frame.size.width;
    }
    [scroll addSubview:imgWordView];
    [imgWordView release];
}
scroll.contentSize = CGSizeMake(self.view.frame.size.width * numberOfViews, self.view.frame.size.height);
[cell.contentView addSubview:scroll]; 
[scroll release];
```

Having the above code snippet, I run across the fact that I need:

```
-(UIView *) viewForZoomingInScrollView:(UIScrollView *)scrollView {
    return image;
}
```

to zoom my UIImageView in the UIScrollView.  How do i find out which UIImageView is *showing* in the UIScrollview so i can in turn access that UIImageView to get the UIImage in order to return it in `viewForZoomingInScrollView`?

Please explain this as I do not see how we are to track the 'displayed' subview ourselves...

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How do i find out which UIImageView is showing in the UIScrollview so i can in turn access that UIImageView to get the UIImage in order to return it in viewForZoomingInScrollView?

You can track where you are in:

```
- (void) scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)scrollView


CGFloat pageWidth = ScrollView.frame.size.width;
page = floor((self.ScrollView.contentOffset.x - pageWidth / 2) / pageWidth) + 1;
```

That lets me know what "page" of content I'm on as the user scrolls through it.

Comment: +1 and CHK'd ... Thanks!  That worked great.  The only thing I am now wondering is:  What if the "pageWidth(s)" are different between frames of the scrollview?  Or is that not possible.  For instance, in my example, what happens if the images are different widths.  Doesn't that screw this answer up?

Comment: I'm not sure - well, yeah I guess you COULD do that - sounds tough though, as the math isn't as straight forward at that point. I'm assuming you can make 'em any size you want because you control the frames and add them as subviews to the UIScrollView. G'luck though!

Answer (score 0):

You could subclass the UIImageView class and implement the touch methods.

Answer (score 0):

```
-(void)scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)scrollView{
    int page_ = (int)round(scrollView.contentOffset.x /scrollView.frame.size.width);
}
```